# Codeigniter routes with arguments

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want something like this but it wont work, that means I am doing it wrong.

```
$route['print/:num'] = "user/doprint/goprint/:num";
```

Let me explain. I have a controller `doprint` under `user` folder and the `goprint` is a method inside `doprint` which accepts a `id` as argument. Now i dont want the users to visit it by `mydomain.com/user/doprint/goprint/2`. I want them to visit it as `mydomain.com/print/2`.

my controller is as below

```
class Doprint extends User_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data['subview'] = 'print';
        $this->load->view('main_layout', $data);
    }

    public function goprint($id=NULL)
    {
        $data['model'] = $this->usermodel_model->get($id);

        $data['subview'] = 'print';
        $this->load->view('main_layout', $data);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route rule syntax is [(per the documentation)](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html):

```
$route['print/(:num)'] = "user/doprint/goprint/$1";
```